# node-red: Failed to install node-red-contrib-db2-for-i package

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, node-red

hi need some help please, i try to install the node-red-contrib-db2-for-i package  on node-red (i used node red as a service on ibm cloud) but it fail. i have this bug :Failed to install: node-red-contrib-db2-for-i.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That package is explicitly for connecting to IBM DB2 running on iSerise and need Node-RED to be running on iSerise hardware as well.

It will NOT run on a x64 Linux machine.

From the README for the node:

> **Prerequisites**
>
> If you use the latest package version (>=0.1.5) :
>
> 5733OPS is not used anymore (Deprecated). A prerequisite is to install
> the Node.js iDB Connector idb-connector (done automatically when
> installing this package if not already present) with Node.js (version
> 8 and later) using a yum install. **This node has to run on Node.js /
> Node-RED on IBM i** (Native driver) but there will be soon an ODBC
> alternative :)